# Setting up /status page of php-fpm on Apache2

Tags: php, apache2

I'm trying to set up the /status page of php-fpm on apache, but i'm getting a 404 error and i can't know why. I'm not expert at neither Apache2 or php, and i been struggling with this a couple days, so i'm here for some help.

This is my apache2.conf settings. And i also have another site hosted on apache with a Directory config:

```
<LocationMatch "/fpm-status">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
ProxyPass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/fpm-status
</LocationMatch>
```

This is my php5.6 settings

```
listen = /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
listen.backlog = 65535
user = www-data
group = www-data
pm.status_path = /fpm_status
```

When i try to curl over http://localhost/fpm-status this message appears:

```
File not found.
```

On apache2 logs this appears when i try to acces that path:

```
AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/a9428050ab9bb3f17c5e33343da94fd8

Seems you may be missing an Alias.

Comment: Thanks! That post helped me to change some things, but i didn't want to acces the realtime fpm-status page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I made multiple changes and then it worked, i don't know what certainly was, so i listed them.

1. Changed "fcgi://localhost/fpm-status" to "fcgi://localhost/"
2. Changed "pm.status_path = /fpm_status" to "pm.status_path = /status"
3. service apache2 restart
4. service php5.6-fpm restart
5. Then curl to http://localhost/status and worked as expected